# overable unary operator expected in c#

Tags: c#, character, declaration, unary-operator

When I mention

```
char operator;
```

It is giving an error unary Operator expected in c#.

SO when It mention as give extern and the default value in android is '\u0000'

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please share you code.

Comment: And perhaps ask a question?

Comment: namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }
      char operator;
        private Button btnC,btnOne,btnTwo,btnThree,btnFour,btnFive,btnSix,btnSeven,btnEight,btnNine,btnZero,btnPlus,btnMinus,btnDiv,btnMul,btnEqual,btnSqrt,btnDot,btnBack;
 //private EditText eNum;
 public static float firstValue = 0;
 public static float secondValue = 0;
 public static String thirdValue = " ";

Comment: You _are_ allowed to edit your question...

Answer (score 6):

`operator` is a reserved word in C#.  If you want to use it as an identifier then you must precede it with `@`, or just choose a different name altogether:

```
char operator;  // Invalid, operator is a reserved word.

char oper;      // Valid.
char @operator; // Also valid.
```

The error message stems from the fact that the compiler thinks that you are trying to overload an operator, and so it is expecting the `operator` keyword to be followed by an operator, as in:

```
static char operator+(Foo a, Foo b) { ... }
```